# How to rotate axis label of plotly parallel coordinates plot?

Tags: matplotlib, plotly, rotation, axis-labels, parallel-coordinates

How to rotate axis label of plotly parallel coordinates plot?

The following image is what I wan to do:
[image]

I attached a source script:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.iris()
fig = px.parallel_coordinates(df, color="species_id",
                              dimensions=['sepal_width', 'sepal_length', 'petal_width',
                                          'petal_length'],
                              color_continuous_scale=px.colors.diverging.Tealrose,
                              color_continuous_midpoint=2)
fig.show()
```